# PyMC3: How to create multiple random walks?

Tags: pymc, pymc3

I want to create several random walk variables in PyMC3, or rather, stack several random walks into a single variable. I know I can create a single random walk of 100 steps like this:

```
with pm.Model() as model():
    z = pm.GaussianRandomWalk('z', mu=0, sd=1, shape=100)
```

But let's say I want to create 20 random walks, each of length 100. If I write this,

```
with pm.Model() as model():
    z = pm.GaussianRandomWalk('z', mu=0, sd=1, shape=(20,100))
```

Does that make every row a random walk, so I have 20 instances of 100 steps each? Or does it make every column a random walk, so I have 100 instances of 20 steps each?

Answer (score 0):

You will have 100 instances of 20 steps each.

The time-series distributions in PyMC3 is not very rigour - it was designed with only 1D time series in mind, so do be careful when you are working with multiple time-series.